# Can you code a shell for Linux using Windows OS and Dev-C++ IDE? Do shells work the same way for both operating systems?

Tags: c, linux, windows, shell, unix

I'm studying computer engineering and we have a class called operating systems where they lecture us about how OSes handle stuff etc. This week we were given a homework which requests us to code a shell that works on Linux. The problem is, they tought us literally nothing on how to code a shell so we are supposed to do some research and figure it out.

I found this guide online and it seemed perfect to me: [link](https://brennan.io/2015/01/16/write-a-shell-in-c/)
Code, with explanations, what else could I ask for.

Now, I'm using a Windows PC and I use Dev-C++ IDE with GCC compiler. Can I code a shell that works on Linux with my current setup or do I have to install Linux? Are there any major differences between how shells run on these OSes?

Comment: Linux and Windows are quite different. You need to target Linux with your development tools. I don't know if Dev-C++ IDE offers that option (I'm not familiar with it). I think the latest Visual Studio does offer Linux as a target. Once you build the program, you need a Linux shell to run it on. If you're using Windows 10, there's actually a real Ubuntu Bash shell available for it that you can run it on. You just need the latest Windows 10 build.

Comment: For more details you can check **Silberschatz Operating System Concepts 9th edition** book (chapter 3). It contains exactly what you want to know and do, it will help you a lot during the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write a shell for Linux, you want to target GNU/Linux which is basically POSIX with some extensions.

Dev-C++ by default uses MinGW GCC as its compiler, providing a Win32 API.

Win32 and POSIX are completely and fundamentally different. A shell written for one will not even slightly resemble the other.

Instead, you have several options:

- Dev-C++ can optionally use Cygwin GCC, providing a more GNU/Linux-like experience on Windows. You need to take great care not to rely on any Cygwin-specific functionality like how it automatically translates pathnames and line terminators. You'll still need access to a Linux install to verify that it works.
- Windows 10 lets you install WSL, a more modern Linux compatibility layer for Windows. Dev-C++ doesn't explicitly states it support it, so you may need to edit and compile separately, and may lose debugging functionality. You'll still need access to a Linux install to verify that it works.
- Just run Linux in a VM. The only thing to care about is getting your shell working.

I would suggest saving yourself a ton of trouble right now and just download/install an Ubuntu image in VirtualBox.

Comment: You missed one important option. Visual Studio 2017 allows you to target Linux. You can author code, compile it, and debug it right in the WSL.